# After Django uses `mysql.connector.django` as the database ENGINE, how to print the executed SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, django

The database configuration is as follows:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html

As the title?

Previously django.db.backends, I added the following configuration in setting.py, print execution SQL statement。

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your logging configuration doesn't work just like that is because, most likely, your `settings.DEBUG = False`.

This is something that is stated in the Django docs, at [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-db-backends), where it says (emphasis mine):

> For performance reasons, SQL logging **is only enabled when
>   settings.DEBUG is set to True**, regardless of the logging level or
>   handlers that are installed.

So I assume you don't want to see every SQL query in production, so change `settings.DEBUG` to `True`, **in development mode** and it will work, I just gave it a try. Make sure your `DEBUG` attribute is not overridden by some `env_var` or by some other mechanism. The last value of `settings.DEBUG` should be `True` in order for this to work. And again, do this **only in development mode**.

The reason why messing with the logging settings doesn't work is because the `settings.DEBUG` attribute controls whether Django uses a `CursorDebugWrapper` (which logs all queries it executes), instead of a `CursorWrapper` (which does not). This happens [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fbb83fefd43a89d1a802d77dcc3a9c9ac15a5afa/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L151).

If you want it to work with `settings.DEBUG = False` (**not recommended**), then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768027/turn-off-sql-logging-while-keeping-settings-debug) on how to force the DB to use the `CursorDebugWrapper`.

---